# formatting string into date in matplotlib 3.1

Tags: python, matplotlib

A tutorial for older versions of python and matplotlib contains code like this:

```
def graphRawFX ():
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt',
                              unpack=True,
                              delimiter=',',
                              converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40),(0,0), rowspan=40,colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

graphRawFX()
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

> The strpdate2num class was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use time.strptime or dateutil.parser.parse or datestr2num instead.
>     `converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})`

Here is one row of the data for more information:

```
20130501000000,1.55358,1.55371
```

so how do I turn that string into dates using matplotlib 3.1?

Comment: The row of data you have provided, is it 01st of may, 2013?

Comment: @Amit yes. and the rest is hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: I'd try with `converters={0:lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what the warning is asking you to do is use time.strptime function to convert from string to time. You may want to change the first line.

```py
import time
date,bid,ask =np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt',unpack=True,delimiter=',',converters={0:time.strptime(mdates,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
```

This is as much I can see based on the error/warning and the cose that was given.

After conversation, I realized that mdates is actually a matplotlib module. Thus suggesting a change. Please try it out.

```py
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',', converters={0: lambda x: mdates.datestr2num(x.decode('utf8'))})
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'module'>
@Amit

Comment: Yes, I assumed mdates is a string. There was little before that to tell otherwise. My assumption was wrong. Is there a function on the class to cast to string first?

Comment: the code on the reply above didn't work either because datetime has no attribute 'strptime'. and no there is no such function. i've copied the whole project in here.

Comment: is there an import such as "import matplotlib.dates as mdates"?

Comment: yes. these are all the imported functions if thats what you mean. i apologize if i don't understand 100% i am fairly new at this. 
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import datetime

Comment: I have edited the answer. Look below the original answer

Comment: yes it did man. thank you very very much!! only, on the x axis of the graph, the dates are kinda jumbled together like they interfere with each other a little. how would you suggest i give them a little rotation?

Comment: @Mahdi_J Thank you. Can you post a pic in your question, so that I have a better idea of the situation.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/onk3j7  ... there is a screenshot. look at the bottom of the picture. the dates are mixed together @Amit

Comment: Yes. plt.xticks(rotation=90) should do the trick. May be just after the above line that I have posted or at a suitable place. All the best.

Comment: @Mahdi_J Normally I would not ask but if you think this is "a" solution, please mark it as a solution. Might be helpful to somebody in future. Thank you.